# How to use double indexing to redefine matrix values

Tags: matrix, octave, indexing

Say I have a matrix `A`:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
```

I can use double indexing to retrieve, say, the values exceeding 3 in the third row:

```
>> B = A(2,:)((A(2,:)>3))
>> B = 4
```

However, using double indexing to redefine matrix values doesn't work:

```
>> A(2,:)((A(2,:)>3)) = 0
>> error: () must be followed by . or close the index chain
```

How can I accomplish this without putting `A(2,:)` into a variable, performing the operation and putting it back into `A(2,:)` again?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer literally 1 second after posting. The key is to not use double indexing.

```
>> A(2,A(2,:)>3) = 0
```

Comment: In general, EXPR() is not valid MATLAB syntax, where EXPR is an arbitrary expression. There's a special case where this syntax is valid, namely, with cell arrays.

Comment: @PhillipCloud the OP didn't specify but from his example I'm guessing he's using Octave. Octave does not have that limitation, you can index anything without using temporary/dummy variables.